# Simple timer I made stops working randomly

Tags: c++, while-loop

Before I start, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        i++;
        cout << i << endl;
        clock_t time = clock() + 1000;
        while (clock() != time);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, basically, it works, however, after a little while it just stops counting down but the program is still running. I'm new to C++ programming and I don't know how to fix this. Could somebody help me out?

EDIT: I'm not wondering how to fix my program still running, I'm wondering how to fix it not outputting numbers at one point randomly.

Comment: Where are you ever leaving your outer loop?

Comment: Tell me, why do you think `clock()` must coincide exactly with `time` at any point? If you just happen to miss that moment, the inner loop will never end.

Comment: What do you mean "outer loop"?

Comment: @Wanderer `while (true) {` Is it intentinal to be an endless loop? So why are you wondering that your program still runs?

Comment: It's quite unlikely that you'll hit `time` exactly when calling `clock`. Use `<=` instead of `!=`. (And it's even less likely that the program counts *down*.)

Comment: I'm not wondering if my program still runs, when I run the program it counts 1, 2, 3 etc... but then it just randomly stops counting.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now. So basically, if it just happens to not hit what I specified "time" to be, it just does nothing? I'll try to fix it

Comment: @Wanderer Storyteller is right afai can see. Unless `clock()` exactly equals time, `while (clock() != time);` will just sit there looping forever, at which point it won't be able to print.

Comment: @molbdnilo: The answer section may be found below.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Do you have any ideas to how I can make it so that doesn't happen?

Comment: @Wanderer: Yes, you were already told how, both in comments above (for some reason) and in my answer below.

Comment: @Wanderer Lightness added an answer. I'm on my phone so a good answer would be hard to write.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Yeah I'm sorry, I didn't see. No need to be mad at me... Thanks.

Comment: @Wanderer: Nobody's "mad at you"

Answer (score 1):

```
while (clock() != time);
```

If you overshoot `time`, which is very likely given how quickly `clock()` increments, you'll be stuck in that loop forever.

**Use `<=` instead**, so that *any* greater value of `clock()` will break the loop.

As an aside, busy-waiting is *so* 1970. You should prefer a "timed wait" of some kind that blocks until a duration has elapsed.